# DNS lookup failed in WIN7 “cmd” terminal

Tags: windows-7, networking, dns

I've encounter one weird problem:

I have a PC with WIN7, and I can access website (e.g. www.baidu.com) via browse (Chrome or others). I can't get ping response from www.baidu.com in WIN7 cmd terminal. The result of ping is that "can't resolve hostname www.baidu.com".

What's more, I can ping www.baidu.com when I use Xshell5.
I run wireshark to capture DNS request and response and found that when I use browse to access website, I'll capture two DNS requests and responses (one type A DNS first, followed by a type AAAA DNS), but if I use cmd ping, I only capture one DNS request and response (only type AAAA).

The IPv4 address is returned by type A DNS response. So, I can't resolve hostname in the the later case.

The only thing that I want to do is using IPv4 DNS lookup as default option in my WIN7 OS. But, I don't want to disable IPv6 network because I have connectivity both in IPv4 and IPv6.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The command `ping -4 www.baidu.com` is worked. And I capture packets in wireshark, which show that `ping -4` only  generate a type A DNS request and get a valid IPv4 address. So, can I change my WIN7 DNS client service setting which always lookup type A DNS (IPv4) before type AAAA DNS (IPv6)?

Comment: I'm sorry about that I have not illustrated it clearly. In fact, I need use `Git bash` to synchronize local repository with remote repo in GitLab. But `git clone <gitlab-repo-url>` failed because of no DNS response. The problem that I encountered in `git bash` is similar to `cmd`. So, the only thing that I want to do is using IPv4 DNS lookup as default option in my WIN7 OS. But, I don't want to disable IPv6 network because I have connectivity both in IPv4 and IPv6. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, too late to reply you. Your two methods do not work in this problem. I'm still finding solutions. :(

Comment: Yes.... Please see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this problem by following command in `cmd`.

> netsh winsock reset